# Function not working in 2016 server but works in 2012 server

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle

The below function StsExpl.MemoId is getting value of only 4 digits but in DB 8 digits are getting stored

ADD_EXPLANATION_SQL is a query to declare a sequence

```
ADD_EXPLANATION_SQL As String = "DECLARE  next_seq NUMBER;
BEGIN 
SELECT STATUSEXPLANATIONS_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO next_seq FROM dual;
INSERT INTO STATUSEXPLANATIONS (MEMOID,CSFNTYPE,EXPLANATION,PROBLEMCODE,CREATE_DATE,CREATE_BY,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,LAST_UPDATE_BY)  
VALUES(next_seq,:csfn_type,:explanation,:problem_code,SYSDATE,:user_id,SYSDATE,:user_id);
:memo_id := '' || next_seq;
END;"

      Public Shared Sub Add(ByVal StsExpl As StatusExplanation)
            Dim cmd As OracleCommand = Nothing
            Try
                cmd = New OracleCommand()
                cmd.CommandText = ADD_EXPLANATION_SQL
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("csfn_type", StsExpl.CsfnType).DbType = DbType.AnsiString

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("memo_id", "AAAAAAAAAAAA").DbType = DbType.AnsiString
                cmd.Parameters("memo_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("explanation", StsExpl.Explanation).DbType = DbType.AnsiString
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("problem_code", DbUtilities.En(StsExpl.ProblemCode)).DbType = DbType.AnsiString
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", StsExpl.CreatedBy).DbType = DbType.AnsiString

                OracleCommandProcessor.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, "ConnectString")

                StsExpl.MemoId = cmd.Parameters("memo_id").Value
```

Comment: The question is unclear, but whatever the problem is, it has *nothing* to do with the Windows server version. What isn't working, what is the actual error or problem? Are you sure the problem isn't caused by the  query, the values, or using localized strings instead of dates and numbers?

Comment: My guess is that the issue is the SQL code. It has to be a guess because you have chosen not to show us the SQL code. How could that possibly be a good idea?

Comment: There is no error but the value from Database should be of 8 digits. Ex StsExpl.MemoId = 10045678 but i am only getting back 1004

Comment: @jmcilhinney or the use of `AddWithValues()` leads to the wrong parameter type being used. Or the parameter values (which are also missing) contain localized date and number *strings* that get converted to different values on servers with different locales

Comment: @RahulJ put that in the question, although that doesn't explain anything. You haven't posted the query or the parameter values so people have to guess. Whatever the problem is, it's the code. For starters, `AddWithValue` *shouldn't* be used because it may infer the wrong type or size from the parameters. The fact you had to put dummy long values or explicitly set lengths and types proves that you've already encountered those problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I was about to comment on the data types. It seems bizarre to be calling `AddWithValue` and then specifying the data type when the whole point of `AddWithValue` is to infer the data type. The code should be calling `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` and it should be specifying an `OracleDbType` value to fix the data type as well as providing the direction where appropriate too.

Comment: Fix the code first - use `Add` with names, types, sizes *and* directions and set the value to the generated parameters.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I suspect the OP encountered conversion problems but instead of using `Add` just tried to get `AddWithValue` to work. In the end, it's more code than using `Add`

Comment: The value of `:memo_id` is never used in the query so it should be an `OutputParameter` with no value. It's a **number**, not a string, so its type shouldn't be AnsiString. It should be a numeric type eg `DbType.Int32` or `DbType.Int64`

Comment: Frankly, both the query and the code look like an attempt to cover up bugs instead of fixing them - `:memo_id := '' || next_seq` tries to convert the number into a string by appending it to an empty string. Which wouldn't be needed if the parameter wasn't an AnsiString. And when the number grew too big, someone tried to force the length with `AddWithValue("memo_id", "AAAAAAAAAAAA")`